# Regex function to find all sequence of digits

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new to Python and I just started learning regex. I'm trying to define a function that takes as input a string containing zero or more sequences of digits and returns a list of all sequences of digits in the string and sorts them. If there isn't it will print that there isn't any.

Here's my code:

```
def DigitSequence(string):
    pattern=re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
    k=re.findall(pattern,string)
    if len(k)!=0:
        return(sorted(k))
    else:
        return('None')

print( DigitSequence("My number is 98765 and my friend\'s number is 12345.") )
#This should return me ['12345','98765']. And it does.
```

But is there any better way to do it. Are there any cases I would miss if I do this. I thought of using `pattern=re.compile(r'\d*')` but I felt it was equivalent to what I did. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `\d` is exactly the same as `[0-9]`, however the quantifiers you used in those patterns are different. `*` matches the preceding entity zero or more times, while `+` matches one or more times. So yeah, in many cases those two patterns will give you the same result, but there's an important distinction.

Comment: Yes. I got the same result.

Comment: What about the cases...would I be missing any. Should I put + or * so that the result won't be changed in case there's an alphanumeric term in the string.

Comment: Ohh yeah..you mean the spaces. I did get those so i wrote another line to clean them but i felt thats not the best way to do it.

Comment: @HeapOverflow So you mean this won't work for single digits? Then how can I capture both?  Is there such a regex term or can i write some condition: pattern=re.compile(r'\d+|\d') . something like this?

Comment: `\d` is not exactly the same as `[0-9]` if using python 3, and if the string contains not only ASCII characters. It also matches full-width digits (０１２３４５６７８９).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall()` is on the right track. Some additional points to note:

1. An uncompiled regex string can be passed directly into `re.findall()`.
2. If full-width digits are wanted, use `r"\d+"`. Otherwise use `"[0-9]+"`.
3. Sorting order: `99` before `111`? Or `'1'11` before `'9'9`?
4. Separate printing logic and parsing logic.

Code:

```
import re

def digital_sequence(s, sort_literal=False, fullwidth_digits=False):
    """Get sorted list of numbers.

    Args:
        s (str): arbitrary string
        sort_literal (bool): literal sort
        fullwidth_digits (bool): accept full-width digits

    Returns:
        list
    """
    r = r"\d+" if fullwidth_digits else r"[0-9]+"
    k = None if sort_literal else lambda x: int(x)
    return sorted(re.findall(r, s), key=k)

def print_ls(ls):
    """Customized list printing: list contents or "None".

    Args:
        ls (list): input list

    Returns:
        None
    """
    print(ls) if len(ls) > 0 else print("None")

s1 = "99 and 112 and １２"
s2 = "abc"
print_ls(digital_sequence(s1))  # ['99', '112']
print_ls(digital_sequence(s2))  # None
print_ls(digital_sequence(s1, sort_literal=True))  # ['112', '99']
print_ls(digital_sequence(s1, fullwidth_digits=True))  # ['１２', '99', '112']
```